# How to log everything on Rust or how to log more than one thing?

Tags: logging, rust

I couldn't find easy information about how to log properly on Rust. I'm doing like this:

```
use log::{debug, error, info, warn};

fn main() {
    env_logger::init();
    info!("test info");
    error!("test error");
}
```

How do I activate both info and error?

```
RUST_LOG="info,error" cargo run
```

won't activate both (none of them get activated), but

```
RUST_LOG="info" cargo run
```

works.

Also, how to activate everything?

Comment: `RUST_LOG="TRACE" cargo run` https://giphy.com/gifs/movie-film-gary-oldman-Ca7gy6EZqdH32

Comment: BTW doc https://docs.rs/env_logger/0.8.3/env_logger/#enabling-logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log levels are hierarchical, meaning that if you set the level to `info`, `info` messages and all levels above it will be captured. Only messages with a lower priority than the enabled level are filtered out:

- `error`
- `warn`
- `info`
- `debug`
- `trace`

Being the lowest level, `trace` will capture all logs:

```sh
RUST_LOG="trace" cargo run
```